# Can I enter Austria with a German issued type D visa?

Tags: europe, covid-19

I have a German issued type D visa (no residence permit yet) and I have a valid reason to enter Germany listed by [Bundespolizei](https://www.bundespolizei.de/Web/DE/04Aktuelles/01Meldungen/2020/03/200317_faq.html;jsessionid=42CB91A6A7A366F53EF61B2200D18A51.1_cid289?nn=5931604). In other words, I can enter Germany right now. And, as I understand, I can travel to Austria from Germany when my quarantine is over (or when I test negative which waives the quarantine requirement). I was wondering if it is possible for me to enter Austria directly and quarantine there? Currently at Turkey.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.